# Bootstrap Switch with default value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `Bootstrap-switch` 2.0 with `jQuery`. I have a radio button that is initially not checked.

Based on checked/not checked, I am hiding/showing `div` tags using `jQuery`.

When page loads first time, how can I run this query so appropriate `div` tags appear(initially nor checked)?

```
$('#preAuth').bootstrapSwitch();
$('#preAuth').bootstrapSwitch('setState', false); 
$('#preAuth').on('switch-change', function(e, data) {
    if(data.value) {
        $("#profile").hide();
        $("#CCInfo").show();          
    } else {
        $("#profile").show();
        $("#CCInfo").hide();

    };
});
```

Comment: I can add a small javaScrip to execute else statement with a seperate function. But I am tryin gto see if I can do it using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution i have found from other threads. Thanks to stackoverflow.

```
$(window).load(function(){    
 setPreAuth();    
});

function setPreAuth(){
   $('#preAuth').bootstrapSwitch();
   $('#preAuth').bootstrapSwitch('setState', false); 
   $("#profile").hide();
   $("#CCInfo").show();       

}
```